# When is "labor" countable and what does "labors" mean exactly?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, singular-vs-plural, nouns, uncountable-nouns

I saw a line in the English subtitles of a non-English show:

> Stop playing. Go all out to fight me, or you will end up using up all of your **labors**.

I first went and made sure the subtitles were produced by an American company and supposedly by native speakers of American English. The exact meaning of **labors** here appears to be *energy* or *power*. Although the meaning of the sentence is apparent, I am having a hard time having this usage corroborated by dictionaries. I have checked M-W, Oxford Online, Macmillan, Cambridge, and Google Dictionaries for the plural usage of **labor**. Weirdly enough, many dictionaries don't have entries for a countable/plural noun usage of **labor**.

There is *only one entry* in Macmillan that includes **labors**, however, it also specifies that this usage is **uncountable**:

> **labor** or **labors** [**UNCOUNTABLE**] FORMAL work that involves effort, especially physical effort

If Macmillan is correct, then should I say:

> Hercules' labors **is** (or *are*) depicted in detail in the book.

Merriam Webster, on the other hand, doesn't have an entry for the plural **labors**, but there is one in Merriam Webster Kids Dictionary (lol) that defines **labor** as a *task*. However, these definitions (*task* and *work*, which are basically the same) don't match the usage at issue, which most likely means *energy* or *power*. Is the usage in my original question correct? Also is **labors** uncountable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Labor** is uncountable when it refers to effort or work  in the abstract, or to those who labor *en masse*.

> Labor was something he had never known or wanted to know, being born with a silver spoon in his mouth.
>
> Labor was divided in respect to the proposed tariffs.

**Labors** refers to *instances* of effort or work, as in

> The sculpture depicts the twelve labors of Hercules, which are as follows: ...

**Labors** can also refer to a multiplicity of efforts presented as a unity or monolith:

> She was rewarded  with a corner office for her labors.

There, you could paraphrase "her labors" as "all her hard work".

Answer (score -3):

It's archaic and possibly inaccurate.

Here is a more contemporary translation of your subtitle:

> Stop playing. Come out and fight me, or risk wasting all your effort.